# How to remove keys and data elements from a JSON in karate when the key has a dot

Tags: karate

I have a JSON object that has keys and object elements in the below format.

{UTC Time: String}

**Example:**

```
{"2020-12-14T14:00:00.000Z":"AVAILABLE","2020-12-15T16:00:00.000Z":"AVAILABLE"}
```

I want to remove an element from this array using it's key (UTC Time). The key will be stored in a variable since it is a dynamically generated value during the run time.

I have so far tried to remove the element by using the remove command and karate.remove.
With remove the element remains in the JSON without any error and with karate.remove I get below error message. This error message made me think that this happens due the period(.) that is in the key.

```
javascript evaluation failed: karate.remove('list', '$.' + timeslot), Missing property in path $['2020-12-15T16:00:00']
```

Simplified Code

```
Given json list = {"2020-12-14T14:00:00.000Z":"AVAILABLE","2020-12-15T16:00:00.000Z":"AVAILABLE"}
And def timeslot = '2020-12-15T16:00:00.000Z'
And remove list.timeslot
And karate.remove('list', '$.' + timeslot)
And print list
```

Please advice me how to remove this element from the JSON. Thanks